# Brezis' Exercise 5.30.4: an orthonormal basis of $L^2(0, 1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, alternative-proof

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*

> Let $(e_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be an orthonormal sequence in $H := L^2 (0, 1)$ with the real inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$. Fix $p \in H$.
>
> 1. Prove that
>    $$
>    \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left | \int_0^t p(s) e_n (s) \, \mathrm d s \right |^2 \le \int_0^t |p(s)|^2 \, \mathrm d s
>    \quad \forall t \in (0, 1). \tag{1}
>    $$
> 2. Deduce that
>    $$
>    \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 \left | \int_0^t p(s) e_n (s) \, \mathrm d s \right |^2  \mathrm d t \le \int_0^1 (1-t) |p(t)|^2 \, \mathrm d t. \tag{2}
>    $$
> 3. Let $E := \{e_1, e_2, \ldots\}$. Assume here that $\operatorname{span} E$ is dense in $H$. Prove that (1) and (2) become equalities.
> 4. Conversely, assume here that equality holds in (2) and that $p \neq 0$ a.e. Prove that $\operatorname{span} E$ is dense in $H$.

1. Could you have a check on my attempt on (4.)?
2. Is there an approach that sidesteps the separability of $H$?

---

Integrating both sides of (1) w.r.t $t$, we get (2). It follows from equality holding in (2) that equality holds in (1) for a.e. $t \in (0,1)$. By continuity, equality holds in (1) for all $t \in (0,1)$. Assume the contrary that $E$ is not dense in $H$. Because $H$ is separable, there is an orthonormal sequence $(e'_n)_{n \ge 1}$ such that $\langle e_n, e'_m \rangle=0$ for all $n,m \ge 1$ and that $\operatorname{span} (E \cup E')$ is dense in $H$. Here $E' := \{e'_1, e'_2, \ldots\}$. We have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left | \int_0^t p(s) e_n (s) \, \mathrm d s \right |^2  + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left | \int_0^t p(s) e'_n (s) \, \mathrm d s \right |^2 
= \int_0^t |p(s)|^2 \, \mathrm d s
\quad \forall t \in (0, 1).
$$

Then
$$
\int_0^t p(s) e'_n (s) \, \mathrm d s = 0 \quad \forall t \in (0, 1), \forall n \ge 1.
$$

Then
$$
pe'_n = 0 
\quad \text{a.e.}
\quad \forall n \ge 1.
$$

Because $p \neq 0$ a.e., $e'_n =0$ a.e. for all $n \ge 1$, which is a contradiction! This completes the proof.